# How to use trait in Laravel model factory?

Tags: php, laravel

If Model factroy is as below then how to use Trait getData() in here?

This code not worked.

```
<?php

use App\Working;
use App\Traits\Calculate;

...

    $factory->define(App\Working::class, function  (Faker\Generator $faker) {        
       ...    
       $getData = $this->getData();        
       ...     
       return['get_data' => $getData];

    }
```

**Error message:**

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::getData()

**Exception trace:**

1   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::{closure}(Object(Faker\Generator), [])
      G:\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:263

2   call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Faker\Generator), [])
      G:\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:263

Comment: Does it show any errors?

Comment: @Script47, check updated, thx.:)

Comment: you must have an error in namespace

Comment: is this whithin a seeder? if so, could you post this as well (or at least all structural elements)

Comment: @nozzleman, no this is in the ModelFactory at factories, thx.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php - Are you using `use`?

Comment: you need to put the trait into a class in order for it to work. you have some `...` in Your sample code which are likely obfuscating information nessecary to solve your problem. this is what is meant by minimal working sample.

Comment: Traits are like class mixins. No class means no trait

Comment: in other words: what does `$this` refer to in your code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably not what you're looking for but here goes:

You can create an inline class that defines a function that returns the real function you want to use. That inline class can use a trait.

Note: Anonymous classes were added in PHP 7

```
<?php

use App\Working;
use App\Traits\Calculate;

// ...
$factory->define(App\Working::class, (new class {
     use Calculate;
     public function generatorFunction() {
         return function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
             // ...
             $getData = $this->getData();
             // ...
             return ['get_data' => $getData];

         };
     }
 })->generatorFunction());
```

**Update:**

Since Laravel 8 model factories are now classes instead of functions so can use traits making the above solution unnecessary.